# Help displaying png files which require scrolling/zooming and sufficient image quality

Tags: blackberry, png

We are attempting to port a very simple application from android/iphone to blackberry.  The application is simply a tool which allows the user to navigate and view png files which are pages in a reference manual.  On iphone/android, we used the webviewer to view the images.  The images range in size from 500x900 to 900x1500.  It all works great on android/iphone. We tried the same thing on the blackberry (curve, storm, torch: 5.0, 6.0) but the Blackberry BrowserField does not appear to scroll horizontally when the image is zoomed.  We also tried using ZoomScreen, but the image quality is so poor that the manual pages are unreadable.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how we can implement a functional viewer of these images which allows zooming/scrolling and which provides good readable image quality?

Comment: I am facing same problem. If you find any solution please reply me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I received this answer on the Blackberry forum which appears to work:

You seem to use MainScreen which by default scrolls vertically but not horizontally. To remedy that, create it like this:

MainScreen myScreen = new MainScreen(VERTICAL_SCROLL | HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

or, if you extend it, put something like this as the first line of your custom screen constructor:

super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

Answer (score 0):

I Found Solution

BrowserField does not provide the ability to scroll implicitly. Instead it is the BrowserField's container's responsibility to implement scrolling.

```
HorizontalFieldManager  bfContainer = new HorizontalFieldManager(HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
BrowserField bField = new BrowserField(bFieldConfig);
bfContainer.add(bField);
add(bfContainer);
```